# My text is wrapping around my icon and I don't know to stop that, also I can't use fill on my SVG logo

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a 4 col grid and a `<ul>` , inside of it I have an icon and a `<span>`, but I don't know how to repair the text to not go under the icon and stay inline with my icon like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gier4.jpg. Mine look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJO5j.jpg.
Also the logo is a problem,  `fill` doesn't work on it.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<footer class="huddle-footer">
        <div class="contacting-details">
          <img class="footer-logo" src="images/logo.svg" alt="huddle logo" />
          <ul class="detail flex-gap">
            <li>
              <ion-icon class="address-icon" name="location-outline"></ion-icon>
              <span class="location mg-left">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
              </span>
            </li>
            <li class="info">
              <ion-icon class="address-icon" name="call-outline"></ion-icon>
              <span class="phone-number"> +1-543-123-4567</span>
            </li>
            <li class="info">
              <ion-icon class="address-icon" name="mail-outline"></ion-icon>
              <span class="email-address">example@huddle.com</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

and here is the CSS code:

```
.footer-logo {
  margin-bottom: 3.6rem;
}
.huddle-footer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
  background-color: var(--Very-Dark-Cyan);
  height: 50vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  padding: 9.6rem 9.6rem 6.4rem 9.6rem;
}
.address-icon {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  fill: hsl(193, 100%, 96%);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.info {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.6rem;
}
.flex-gap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2.4rem;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: you need to create a sandbox cox I tried copy pasting your code to some online editor and it works fine.

Comment: Try putting display: flex to your li

.detail li { display: flex }

Comment: I added it on github : https://github.com/ZglobiulViu/problem